# Next Js 13 Fetch not returning cookies

Tags: next.js, fetch

I tried to fetch my sign in api endpoint with NEXT JS 13, supposedly there will be access_token and refresh_token cookies issued after a successful sign in, unfortunately there is no cookies appear in the browser but then in the header that i console log it shows there are cookies being set, is this a bug or something? (It works previously in NEXT JS 12)

```
import React from 'react'
import TodoList from './TodoList'

const fetchSingle = async () => {
    const res = await fetch
        (`http://localhost:3000/auth/signin`, {
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'test@gmail.com', password: '12345' })
        })
    try {
        return res
    } catch (error) {
        return console.log('Error')
    }

}


export default async function Todos() {

    const response = await fetchSingle()
    console.log(response)

    return (
        <div>
            {/* @ts-ignore */}
            <TodoList />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `Todos` is a server component, the fetch request is made from the server, not the browser. Hence why no cookies show on the browser for that request. You probably want to use a [client component](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#client-components) for your use case.

Comment: So anyone figure this out? I even tried useState to fetch still unable to obtain cookies in browser side. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you must enable cross-origin cookies by setting 'credentials' to 'include':

```
fetch(url, {
    cache: 'force-cache',       // SSG  (getStaticProps)  // default
    cache: 'no-store',          // SSR  (getServerSideProps)
    next: { revalidate: 60 },  // ISR
    credentials: 'include'      // cross-origin cookies
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this,

In my scenario, I’m using Express on the backend; for the CORS configuration, I need to add the following:

```
cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
```

And at my `fetch` request, I need to add at the options:

```
fetch(API_HOST, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: "include",
      })
```

With this, now the browser allows saving cookies from the response header `Set-Cookie`.